# Aligning bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, alignment

So I am coding a website using bootstrap, and a simple problem is plaguing me.
Basically I will have a container, with a row inside, and inside of that I have 3 col-lg-4 columns. my issue is that the columns are not centering, nor are they filling the row. example http://www.connornorvell.com/misc/stack-example.png

As you can see the title "johnny" should be touching the right side of the screen and the title "rafael" should be centered.

I have tried adding row-centered and col-centered classes to my divs, but it doesn't work (row-centered just center aligns the text).

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container breathing-room-bottom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <p class="sans" style="font-weight:500; text-align:;">Connor Norvell
          <br>
          <span2 style="color:#828282;">Art Director
          <br>(555) 555 - 5555
          <br>connor@mggall.com</span2>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <p class="sans" style="font-weight:500; text-align:;">Rafael De La Vega
          <br>
          <span2 style="color:#828282; font-weight:500;">Art Director
          <br>(555) 555 - 5555
          <br>rafael@mggall.com</span2>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <p class="sans" style="font-weight:500; text-align:;">Johnny Presslaur
          <br>
          <span2 style="color:#828282;">Art Director
          <br>(555) 555 - 5555
          <br>johnny@mggall.com</span2>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Everything is bootstrap, except `.sans` (makes text sans serif) and `.breathing-room-bottom` (adds 5% padding to the bottom of the container.

Comment: please remove the inapropriate wording in your example png, then put it inline.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a number of built-in classes for styling. Learn them, use them.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

In this case, the classes you want are: `text-left`, `text-center`, `text-right`

Hope this helps

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container breathing-room-bottom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-left">
      <p class="sans" style="font-weight:500;">Connor Norvell
        <br>
        <span2 style="color:#828282;">Art Director
          <br>(555) 555 - 5555
          <br>connor@mggall.com</span2>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
      <p class="sans" style="font-weight:500;">Rafael De La Vega
        <br>
        <span2 style="color:#828282; font-weight:500;">Art Director
          <br>(555) 555 - 5555
          <br>rafael@mggall.com</span2>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
      <p class="sans" style="font-weight:500;">Johnny Presslaur
        <br>
        <span2 style="color:#828282;">Art Director
          <br>(555) 555 - 5555
          <br>johnny@mggall.com</span2>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you! i have done this, but I was wondering if I could keep the text alignment to left, but have the right column align on the right side. Maybe not possible. If I cant do this I will just align it like you said

Comment: @ConnorNorvell - the right column content *is* on the right side of the container (http://codeply.com/go/cUHbYnytp8). If you want the text on the right you must use text-right.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wanting to set `text-align` to `left`, `center`, and `right` I've made a Plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/B1DdtnCzJY4e1svAhibR?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `text-align` to center like in the first and last column in this fiddle or use the bootstrap alignment class `text-center`, like in the mid column (I recommend this approach).

https://jsfiddle.net/michelefenu/3eL4f1a7/